# Rust Lifetime Problems when sorting an array by key

Tags: rust, lifetime

I encounter some problems, when implementing an `argmax` function. Here is an MVCE (link to [v1 playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=afd12efe57ca5ee7f02729553a3e89b4)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let c = [4,5,6,1];
    let min = argmin(&c);
    println!("{}", min);
}

fn argmin(arr: &[i32]) -> usize {
        arr.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .min_by_key(|(_, v)| v)
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap()
}
```

Which results in some lifetime errors:

```rust
error: lifetime may not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:10:50
   |
10 |             .min_by_key(|(_, v): &(usize, &i32)| v)
   |                                  -             - ^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
   |                                  |             |
   |                                  |             return type of closure is &'2 &i32
   |                                  let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Granted. There is no guarantee that the a reference to the minimum value of the vector outlives the (reference to the) vector from which it's coming. This led me to the following adaptations (link to [v2 playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b9e89b7753fa081e240e1d40b29c74f0)):

```rust
fn main() {
    let c = [4,5,6,1];
    let min = argmin(&c);
    println!("{}", min);
}

fn argmin<'a>(arr: &'a [i32]) -> usize {
        arr.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .min_by_key(|(_, v): &'a (usize, &i32)| v)
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap()
}
```

I would think now, that Rust can figure out that both `c` and its minimum have the same lifetime with the information from the `argmin`'s signature. But what I receive is another compiler error:

```rust
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:34
   |
10 |             .min_by_key(|(_, v): &'a (usize, &i32)| v)
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected reference `&(usize, &i32)`
              found reference `&'a (usize, &i32)`
note: the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 10:25...
  --> src/main.rs:10:25
   |
10 |             .min_by_key(|(_, v): &'a (usize, &i32)| v)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 7:11
  --> src/main.rs:7:11
   |
7  | fn argmin<'a>(arr: &'a [i32]) -> usize {
   |           ^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:34
   |
10 |             .min_by_key(|(_, v): &'a (usize, &i32)| v)
   |                                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ lifetime mismatch
   |
   = note: expected reference `&(usize, &i32)`
              found reference `&'a (usize, &i32)`
note: the lifetime `'a` as defined on the function body at 7:11...
  --> src/main.rs:7:11
   |
7  | fn argmin<'a>(arr: &'a [i32]) -> usize {
   |           ^^
note: ...does not necessarily outlive the anonymous lifetime #1 defined on the body at 10:25
  --> src/main.rs:10:25
   |
10 |             .min_by_key(|(_, v): &'a (usize, &i32)| v)
   |                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

What is happening here? To me it seems like the lifetime in the function signature can't be matched to the one in `min_by_key`. How can we fix this in a proper way, using lifetimes? Can we even do it?

P.S.: I know that this can easily be fixed by just using a clone (`.min_by_key(|(_, v)| v.clone())`) in line 10.

Comment: you can just easily remove the lifetimes and let it handle them.

Comment: @Netwave thanks for the comment. That is what I first tried, have a look at the second code block.

Comment: Interestingly, the even simpler `fn argmin(arr: &[i32]) { let _min = arr.iter().min_by_key(|v| v).unwrap(); }` also fails to build ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d2faef9b85cd4ffb48e475b3c5dbdd53)) with the same lifetime error as the first snippet. I'm curious about the actual problem with that code - it's not like the closure returns the reference to a local value, it returns the reference received in argument, and that reference "obviously" lives long enough. Replacing `min_by_key(|v| v)` with just `min()` compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it is a bit tricky, but it is due because of a double reference. If I'm correct. Notice the double reference `&(usize, &i32)`. So, in reality you are getting a `&usize` and a `&&i32`. For solving that, just **match** the outer reference in the closure:

```rust
fn argmin(arr: &[i32]) -> usize {
        arr.iter()
            .enumerate()
            .min_by_key(|&(_, v): &(usize, &i32)| v)
            .map(|(idx, _)| idx)
            .unwrap()
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c31f93f6ab5b142b87db6001c8679c52)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, that makes the solution clear. So the actual problem was that the double reference `&&i32` has another lifetime than the vector by default?

Comment: @pythonic833, exactly